# Move Columns to next if null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I want to move color forward to next column if the required columns are null however I used COALESCE function but I am unable to get expected result

Below is my table structure

```
ID.        Level1.  Level2.   Level3    Level5 
1.         Xyz.     Null.     Null.     Null
2.         Abc.     Xyz.      Null.     Null
3.         Mno.     Abc.      Xyz.      Null
4.         Ggg.     Mno.      Abc.      Xyz
```

The expected result as below

```
ID.        Level1.  Level2.   Level3    Level5 
1.         Null.    Null.     Null.     Xyz
2.         Null.    Null.     Abc.      Xyz
3.         Null.    Mno.      Abc.      Xyz
4.         Ggg.     Mno.      Abc.      Xyz
```

Comment: please post dml,ddl like the one in answer by Jason,it helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do this with `coalesce()`, another method is simper (believe it or not):

```
select t.*, lv.*
from t outer apply
     (select max(case when l = 1 then lev end) as level5,
             max(case when l = 2 then lev end) as level4,
             max(case when l = 3 then lev end) as level3,
             max(case when l = 4 then lev end) as level2,
             max(case when l = 5 then lev end) as level1             
      from (select lev, row_number() over (order by l desc) as l
            from (values (1, level1), (2, level2), (3, level3), (4, level4), (5, level5) v(l, lev)
            where lev is not null
           ) l
      ) lv;
```

The logic is to unpivot the data on each row and reaggregate the non-`NULL` values.

Comment: I ran your solution against my test data. Rather than shifting values to the right, it simply reversed the column order for L1 -> L4 to L4 -> L1... Sorry, can't find a way to post the results so that they are legible in this area...

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken before... The correct values are under the correct columns. The fact they were displayed in reverse order threw me off. Mea Culpa.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's producing the desired results...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestDate', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestDate;

CREATE TABLE #TestDate (
    ID CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    Level_1 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    Level_2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    Level_3 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    Level_4 VARCHAR(10) NULL
    );
INSERT #TestDate (ID, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3, Level_4) VALUES 
    ('1.', 'Xyz.', Null, Null, Null),
    ('2.', 'Abc.', 'Xyz.', Null, Null),
    ('3.', 'Mno.', 'Abc.', 'Xyz.', Null),
    ('4.', 'Ggg.', 'Mno.', 'Abc.', 'Xyz');

--  SELECT * FROM #TestDate td;

WITH 
    cte_NewLevel AS (
        SELECT 
            td.ID,lvl.LevelNum, lvl.LebelValue,
            NewLevel = 5 - COUNT(lvl.LebelValue) OVER (PARTITION BY td.ID ORDER BY lvl.LevelNum DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
        FROM
            #TestDate td
            CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (1, td.Level_1), (2, td.Level_2), (3, td.Level_3), (4, td.Level_4) ) lvl (LevelNum, LebelValue)
        )
SELECT 
    nl.ID,
    Level_1 = MAX(CASE WHEN nl.NewLevel = 1 THEN nl.LebelValue END),
    Level_2 = MAX(CASE WHEN nl.NewLevel = 2 THEN nl.LebelValue END),
    Level_3 = MAX(CASE WHEN nl.NewLevel = 3 THEN nl.LebelValue END),
    Level_4 = MAX(CASE WHEN nl.NewLevel = 4 THEN nl.LebelValue END)
FROM
    cte_NewLevel nl
GROUP BY
    nl.ID;
```

Results...

```
ID   Level_1    Level_2    Level_3    Level_4
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1.   NULL       NULL       NULL       Xyz.
2.   NULL       NULL       Abc.       Xyz.
3.   NULL       Mno.       Abc.       Xyz.
4.   Ggg.       Mno.       Abc.       Xyz
```